# How to deploy BigQuery and access BigQuery to public internet?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to BigQuery as datawarehouse in my company. How BigQuery can access to all of data team member? Is install BigQuery in SSH Compute Engine ? Or don't need install BigQuery in SSH Compute Engine and just give user access in IAM then data team member will access BigQuery table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I want to use BigQuery as a data warehouse in my company. How  BigQuery, can access to all of the data team members?**

BigQuery is a completely serverless and cost-effective enterprise data warehouse. It has built-in machine learning and BI that works across clouds, and scales with your data.

You can grant different permissions to each member based on their needs. For example, a member who only wants to read the bigquery data can be given the `BigQuery Data Viewer` role and the member who wants to update the bigquery data can be given the `BigQuery Data Editor` role. For more information, you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#role_types).

**Is install BigQuery in SSH Compute Engine  or don't need to install BigQuery in SSH Compute Engine and just give user access in IAM then data team members will access BigQuery tables?**

If you just want to access bigquery through a browser interface then there is no need to install BigQuery libraries. But if you want to access bigquery through the client library from your local machine then you need to install the necessary libraries. For more information, you can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries)

If you are accessing bigquery from the gcp ssh compute engine then there is no need to install client libraries(BigQuery). You can run your code on this Linux machine without installing any libraries. You can take a look at this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598665/) also.

**To access BigQuery through the internet, you can follow the below steps:**

1. Create a project in the google cloud.
2. Enable the BigQuery api and other necessary api’s
3. Create a service account and give required permissions.
4. Download  service account JSON key file
5. Use the JSON key file for authentication.
6. you can interact with BQ using a client (by installing necessary libraries) or [CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool)

To access the bigquery through the browser interface, your team members need the required permission based on their role.

For more information you can follow this [link.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts)

Comment: So, how my team can access bigquery interface in public internet?

Comment: I edited my answer to access BigQuery through the public internet  and I hope I answered your question. If yes please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

By default, granting access to a project also grants access to datasets within it. Default access can be overridden on a per-dataset basis.

The access is easiest granted through pre-defined IAM roles: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-basic-roles

Dataset specific access can be granted as described here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/control-access-to-resources-iam

Users that are registered in IAM and have the above mentioned roles will be able to access data through the console or API call.

In python this e.g. works through a client as described here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/getting-started#python